# undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length

Tags: g++, centos7

There are several posts citing this (or similar) undefined references, but none of those was of help.

I have code which compiles nicely on gentoo 4.14.83, with both gcc-7.3.0 and gcc-8.2.0.

On CentOS 7 (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)), however, the linker of g++-7.3.1  says:

```
/home/jody/progs/multi_spc_QHG3/kernel/Geography.cpp:68: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
/home/jody/progs/multi_spc_QHG3/kernel/Geography.cpp:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
/home/jody/progs/multi_spc_QHG3/kernel/Geography.cpp:70: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
/home/jody/progs/multi_spc_QHG3/kernel/Geography.cpp:71: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
```

The referenced lines in `Geography.cpp` have simple `new` statements:

```
m_adLatitude   = new geonumber[m_iNumCells];
m_adLongitude  = new geonumber[m_iNumCells];
m_adAltitude   = new geonumber[m_iNumCells]; 
m_adDistances  = new geonumber[m_iNumCells*m_iMaxNeighbors];
```

(the type `geonumber` is actually `double`, `m_iNumCells` and `m_iMaxNeighbors` have type `int`)

Because i need g++ version 7, i use the compiler from devtoolset-7-gcc.x86_64.

Some of the posts i found stated that this error is caused by missing libstdc++, but this is not the case here.

What causes this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you build your program? Compilation and linking? What commands do you use?

Comment: To compile i  do `g++ -c -g Coastal.cpp -o Coastal.o    -g -I../kernel -fopenmp` and to link i use  `g++  -g -Wall -o Coastal Coastal.o -L../kernel -lKernel -lz -lhdf5 -fopenmp`